# FileNotFoundException when trying to save DataFrame to parquet format, with 'overwrite' mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this weird error. I have a routine that reads a dataframe if it exists (or creates one otherwise), modifies it, and then saves it again in the same target path in parquet format, with 'overwrite' mode.

In the first run, when there is no dataframe, I create one, and save it. It generates in the output folder 4 files:

- _SUCCESS.crc
- part-r-<.....>.snappy.parquet.crc
- _SUCCESS
- part-r-<.....>.snappy.parquet

Then, in a second run, I read the dataframe, modify it, and when I try to overwrite it, it throws an exception that the `*part-r-<.....>.snappy.parquet file does not exist*`.

The output folder is empty when the exception occurs, but before the execution of `df.write.parquet(path, 'overwrite')` the folder contains this file.

I tried to set the spark.sql.cacheMetadata to 'false' but it didn't help. The spark.catalog.listTables() returns an empty list so there is no point to refresh anything.

For now, I simply delete the output folder's items, and write the dataframe. It works. But why the original method with 'overwrite' mode fails??

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is when you apply savemode as override then after creating physical plan spark delete the directory you can try savemode as append

Comment: I am facing the same issue and save mode as append also fails while writing into s3 from spark

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RDD's doesn't hold the data like variable , it's just a data structure that knows how to get the data(getPartition) and what to perform as transformation(compute) on that data when an **action is called.**

So what you are doing here is,

*1st time => ... => Save to path A 

2nd time onward => **read from path A** => do some transformation => **Save to path A With Override mode***

Now notice, your actual action is **Save to path A** . Util you call an action, Spark only creates the DAG, which knows when an action will be called where to look for data(Save to path A), how to transform them and where to save/show.

But as you are selecting mode override , Spark in it's execution plan adding to delete the path first, then trying to read that path which is already vacant.

So, as an workaround you can save them either different folder like partition basis, or you can save them in two path one destination and one tmp.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. what I did is I wrote it into a temp location and then read from there and write to the main location. still it fails. any thoughts ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Why this behaviour? Spark should be aware of this inconsistence when creating the planification.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to do here is to cache it -

```
df.cache()
```

Right after you read it from hdfs.

Comment: AFAIK, `cache()` is not an action, thus it does not triggers Spark evaluation.

Comment: Did not work for me, spark still looks to read from the file it just deleted because of the overwrite.