# SparkException part-00005 of parquet file not found

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

When I run the job in spark cluster, it is throwing the below error. Tried multiple jobs, but all failed with the same reason.

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 3 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 44, 172.0.0.0, executor 4): 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/user/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/work/driver-20230223072100-0000/CP712292-202302171800-23.0.0.0-312-1676688839-filter.parquet/part-00005-dd53c462-fc3b-4c76-b4b4-42afd8aedcca-c000.snappy.parquet does not exist
```

Job details: The job reads file from HDFS, convert it to DataSet, and push it to HDFS as parquet file for faster processing. Spark will fetch the parquet file from HDFS and starts aggregating the data as per logic. The issue is, it doesn't get part of parquet file while processing it.

```
System.out.println("Creating parquet file from the created RDD...");
Dataset<Row> testDF = spark.createDataFrame(testRDD, Test.class);

System.out.println("Writing to parquet file...");
testDF.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(inputFile + ".parquet");

System.out.println("Loading parquet file to a Java Dataset...");
Dataset<Row> parquetFileDF = spark.read().parquet(inputFile + ".parquet");
parquetFileDF.createOrReplaceTempView("Test");
Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.sql(query);
```

Cluster details: It's a 10 node Spark and Hadoop cluster running in cluster mode. Version 2.4.4

Can't find any other error logs apart from it.

Comment: after your last query do you write again to the same path (inputFile + ".parquet") ?

Comment: No. we don't write anything back to parquet file

Comment: Looks like the parquet file is being updated while you read it. Is it possible in your situation?

Comment: this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607591/filenotfoundexception-when-trying-to-save-dataframe-to-parquet-format-with-ove

Comment: No.. we aren't updating parquet file once it is created. Also the same was working fine last 2 years and suddenly stopped working